# How to determine the serviceUUID of the discovered peripheral

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, device, core-bluetooth, identifier

My app will have an array of serviceUUIDs with which to discover selected peripherals.  Once a peripheral from that set is discovered, how do I then determine which serviceUUID it has/had to allow it to be discovered?  The UUID of the peripheral's identifier seems to be different than the serviceUUID I gave it in my test code.

Comment: For future questions, you probably want to add the tag "core-bluetooth" so it makes it easy for folks who have the expertise to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the detected service UUIDs out of the advertisement, but they might come in two places depending on whether the advertisement originated from backgrounded iOS devices (which transmit in the "overflow area").

Try something like this to get the list of service UUIDs from both places:

```
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        var detectedServiceUuids = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey] as? [CBUUID] ?? []
        if let detectedOverflowUuids = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataOverflowServiceUUIDsKey] as? [CBUUID] {
            detectedServiceUuids.append(contentsOf: detectedOverflowUuids)
        }
        for detectedServiceUuid in detectedServiceUuids {
            print("I detected serviceUuid: \(detectedServiceUuid)")
        }
    }
```